# Apache hive - how could we compare array column values with other columns in joins

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am new in hive. can any one help to resolve the below issue.

**Table 1:**

```
Column1 Column2

1   1,2,10
2   11,12,13
3   1,2,14
4   20,1,10
5   11,12,13,14
```

**Table 2:**

```
Column1 Column2
1   Purchase
2   Product View
10  Cart Open
11  Checkout
12  Cart Add
13  Cart Remove
14  Cart View
20  Campaign View
```

**Output:**
After joining these table1,table2 the output should coming like below

```
Column1 Column2 DESC
1   1,2,10   Purchase, Product View, Cart Open
2   11,12,13    Checkout, Cart Add, Cart Remove
3   1,2,14  Purchase, Product View
4   20,1,10 Campaign View, Purchase, Cart Open
5   11,12,13,14 Checkout, Cart Add, Cart Remove, Cart View
```

Question 1:

How could we compare the `table1 column2.1, colum2.2, column2.10 with table2 column1 values(1,2,10,11,12,13,14,20)` and make new `column` in `table1`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the below query to get the desired result:

```
SELECT table1.column1 as Column1,
       table1.column2 as Column2,
       collect_set(table2.column2) as DESC
FROM table2,
     table1
WHERE (table1.column2 RLIKE CONCAT('^' , table2.column1, ','))
  OR (table1.column2 RLIKE CONCAT(',' , table2.column1 , '$'))
  OR (table1.column2 RLIKE CONCAT(',' , table2.column1, ','))
GROUP BY table1.column2,
         table1.column1
 ORDER BY table1.column1
```

1. For more information on collect_set(), please refer to the hive documentation. 
   **collect_set(col)** returns a set of objects with duplicate elements eliminated.
2. **RLIKE** (Regex match) is used as we want to match patterns from table2.column1 to table1.column2 text.  Single RLIKE between the 2 columns will not work as '12' will match for value '1', '2' and '12'.
3. **CONCAT** is being used for 3 regular expression conditions:
           Numeral at starting will only have a comma after.
   Numeral in middle will have a comma before and after.
   Numeral at end will only have a comma before.
4. There is no join required and it is being simply worked upon by using existing hive functions.

Comment: Hi Abhishek,Thanks for your reply

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do compare the values if table1. column2 is an array. please see my schema for table1 is column1 int, column2 array <int> . Table2 schema is column1 int, column2 string. Now how can we compare table1.column2[0]== table2.column1

Comment: I know, It has been delayed by a great deal but if you still are looking for an answer please find it below: `SELECT table1.column1 as Column1,
       table1.column2 as Column2,
       collect_set(table2.column2) as DESC
FROM table2,
     table1
WHERE array_contains(table1.column2, table2.column1)
GROUP BY table1.column2,
         table1.column1
` Please select it as an answer if it is what you are looking for :)